# Compare with Date and ID problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
ID Date Intime Outtime

A001   20000501 12:00:00 22:00:00
A001   20000502 14:00:00 22:00:00
A001   20000503 12:00:00 23:00:00
A002   20000501 11:00:00 20:00:00
A002   20000502 13:00:00 21:00:00
```

So on…,

```
Table2

ID Date Intime Outtime

A001 20050501 14:00:00 23:00:00
A002 20050501 08:00:00 16:00:00
```

From the above table

I want to take Table1.ID, Table1.Date, Table2.Intime, Table2.Outtime from Table1 Inner Join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID and Table1.Date = Table2.Date

Getting Duplicated values

```
ID Date Intime Outtime

A001   20000501 14:00:00 23:00:00
A001   20000501 18:00:00 16:00:00
A002   20000501 14:00:00 23:00:00
A002   20000501 18:00:00 16:00:00
```

I tried Left outer Join also. It was showing a same.  How to compare the id and date.

Need query Help?

Comment: Are you sure you got the data right?  The inner join you described would not return those results from that data.  Double-check your data (I think the dates in Table 1 are incorrect.)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525705/compare-with-dates-and-id

Comment: No--very similar, but it is a different question

Comment: @Philip - Always they are not read the question clearly, Simply they told like duplicate.  Thanks for Understand my question.

Comment: @Marc_S. This is my output.

AEAXC001 20080903 17:18:57 17:19:58 00:00:00 00:00:00 
AEAXC001 20080903 17:18:57 17:19:58 09:00:00 17:00:00

See am getting duplicate values.

Comment: OK, so you have one row in Table1, and multiple in Table2, with the same (ID, Date)? Then of course, if you do a INNER JOIN, you'll get multiple results in the end - that's just the way the INNER JOIN works.

Comment: What is other way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do an inner join, you'll only get those rows that are present in both tables (in terms of their ID and Date):

```
SELECT 
  Table1.ID, Table1.Date, 
  Table2.Intime, Table2.Outtime 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table1.Date = Table2.Date

ID     Date       InTime   OutTime
A001   20000501   14:00:00 23:00:00
A002   20050501   08:00:00 16:00:00
```

If you're not getting this, then there's a problem in your data - as I've already mentioned in a previous answer to a previous question.

Check the output of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ID = 'A001' AND Date = '20000501'
```

I bet you get more than one row.....

Marc

Trying to explain further - I still think you're misunderstanding the INNER JOIN or you're trying to accomplish something that can't really be done easily.

Your output is something like this:

```
ID Date Intime Outtime

A001   20000501 14:00:00 23:00:00
A001   20000501 18:00:00 16:00:00
A002   20000501 14:00:00 23:00:00
A002   20000501 18:00:00 16:00:00
```

If you truly get this output from your INNER JOIN, then this means:

- you most like have one row with `ID=A001` and `Date=20000501` in your Table1
- you have two (or more) rows in your Table2 with `ID=A001` and `Date=20000501`

What the INNER JOIN will do is combine row#1 from Table2 with the single row from Table1, and then row#2 from Table2 with the single row from Table1, and so on.

If you have multiple entries with the same (ID,Date) values in Table2, you **will** get duplicates with an INNER JOIN - this is by design, and is not an error - but just the way the INNER JOIN works.